# Pure CSS transform scale from current value

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

When applying a CSS scale transform to an element, is it possible to set the 'from' value as the current scale?

For example, consider the following 2 CSS keyframes used to apply separate growing and shrinking animation transforms:

```
@-webkit-keyframes grow
{
    from { -webkit-transform: scale(0,0); }
    to { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes shrink
{
    from { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); }
    to { -webkit-transform: scale(0,0); }
}
```

This will successfully scale the element it's applied to, but always from 0 to 1 (or vice-versa). If the *shrink* keyframe gets applied before the *grow* keyframe has finished, it has the effect of 'jumping' the scale to 0 before the transform begins.

You can see this effect in this [jsFiddle showing CSS scale transform on mouseover](http://jsfiddle.net/bg6aj/20/)

Notice that if you mouse over the black square and then quickly mouse out, the scale transform is not smooth.

What I'm essentially after is something like the following:

```
@-webkit-keyframes grow
{
    from { -webkit-transform: CURRENT_SCALE; }
    to { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); }
}
```

Comment: Not possible using CSS alone (AFAIK). http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/ describes some techniques to get the current values via JavaScript, maybe you can adapt that.

Comment: This is indeed possible using transitions not animations. See http://jsfiddle.net/G6wME/2/ - forked from @enguerranws js fiddle below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation makes the element go from 0% scale to 100% scale on hover, and from 100% to 0% scale on mouseOut.

I think in this case, the solution could be **setting the basic scale of the element according to its start point** :

```
#output
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FF0000;
  display: inline-block;
   -ms-transform: scale(0,0);
    transform: scale(0,0);  
   -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);  
}
```

In this case, I would harldy recommend **using pure CSS solution**, using transition on :hover : http://jsfiddle.net/bg6aj/21/

You wont have any "jumping" effect :

```
#output
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FF0000;
  display: block;
   -ms-transform: scale(0,0);
    transform: scale(0,0);  
   -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);  
    transition: all .2s;  
   -webkit-transition: all .2s; 
}

#touchPad:hover + #output {
   -ms-transform: scale(1,1);
    transform: scale(1,1);  
   -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
}
```

At this point, you'll have no more jumping effect.
Then : can we do something like :

```
@-webkit-keyframes grow
{
    from { -webkit-transform: scale(0,0); }
    to { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); }
}
```

Answer : quite easy :

```
@-webkit-keyframes grow
{
    0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: scale(0,0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); }
}
```

Which means: take my element (as scale default is 100%), render it with 0% scale at 50% of the animation, and turn it back at 100%. Trying to set something like current_scale doesn't make sense.

Considering that, I'll definitely choose the Transition solution.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the solution at all - the proposed code will simply set the element in an initial 0 scale state, but not change any of the actual transform behaviours.

Comment: If you use CSS transitions, you won't have any jumping effect, which is part of your problem. Let me think about the other part.

Comment: Did you tried something like : @-webkit-keyframes grow
{
    0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: scale(0,0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); }
} ? (updated my answer)

Comment: Thanks, the transition solution definitely seems to be what's needed. Are you able to show how this could be applied via a JS event rather than a :hover selector? Something along the lines of this (which doesn't work) http://jsfiddle.net/bg6aj/27/

Comment: Also, using the 3 phase keyframe suggested would just have the effect of making it full size, then no size, then full size again?

Comment: Yes that's it. I take a look at your fiddle (if JS is really needed, but I would use it in that case)